# Does the SourceForge Clear Case plugin work with Snapshot views?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) with the latest [Clear Case plugin from Source Forge v2.2.14.201202241422](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/).  Our ClearCase server tells me:

```
ClearCase version 7.1.2.0 (Tue Sep 21 12:01:15 EDT 2010) (7.1.2.D100920)
@(#) MVFS version 7.1.2.0 (Tue Aug 10 00:37:25 2010)
cleartool                         7.1.2.0 (Wed Sep 8 12:56:06 2010)
db_server                         7.1.2.0 (Sat Sep 4 01:27:12 2010)
VOB database schema version: 54
```

I have a snapshot view already created on my local machine.  I've imported the project into Eclipse.

EDIT: The snapshot view was created using CCRC (Clear Case Remote Client).

When I click my project in the Project Explorer, and then run Team -> Associate With ClearCase, I get a dialog that says it's scanning the project folder and I get no errors when it finishes. (Nothing in Error Log view either).

I see label decorations (although they are all empty), but other than that, it appears the association didn't actually do anything.

When I select Properties -> Clear Case on the project or any file within it, I get:

```
"The selected resource is not a clear case element".
```

Is there something I need to do to make this work?  Or does the plugin simply not support snapshot views?

FYI, the IBM plugin works in the exact same configuration, however it is horribly implemented, so I'd rather not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use generally the [IBM Eclipse plugin for ClearCase](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html), but I have seen the SourceForge Clear Case plugin works with snapshot view, but **only for base ClearCase, not for CCRC**.

The main difference I saw between the two plugin (beside their behavior/implementation) is that the IBM one *needs* the `.project` and `.classpath` to be where the project files are (and not separate, one in the Eclipse workspace, the others in an external path).

The other difference is in the type of ClearCase client supported:
The IBM ClearCase plugin can also support CCRC views (as opposed to the Sourceforge ClearCase plugin, limited to Base or UCM full ClearCase client).

Comment: (The other alternative would be to downgrade the Sourceforge plugin version and see if the problem persists)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would copy the .project/.classpath into the workspace as my workspace doesn't even have an entry for this project.

Comment: @Jay one quick test you can do is to create a new empty project with the default path (ie the eclipse workspace), then reference from that new project the sources (part of your snapshot view), and finally try to share that new project, and see if the Sourceforge plugin works better then.

Comment: Okay, I created a new, empty Java project.  Then deleted the src directory and linked the src dir from my snapshot view as my src dir.   Not sure what you want me to try next... if I share the project, it wants to know where in my CC view I want to put the new project, and I don't want to mess up what's already there...

Comment: @Jay, that shouldn't mess anything, but if you want to be safe, you can create a second snapshot view, and try the process from there.

Comment: Well, as soon as I choose Share project, it tries to store add the files to the VOB, which I can't do (I don't have access to remove files from CC).  But all of this didn't seem to help any, still no association.  I'd try downgrading the SF plugin, if I had any idea which of them to downgrade to...

Comment: @Jay: so this is consistent with the use of having the Eclipse files (`.project` and `.classpath`) located with the project sources. I cannot help you with the downgrade process. I have only used the IBM ClearCase plugin for the past few years.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  The IBM plugin does work, but makes me work harder.  :)

Comment: @Jay just to be sure, are we talking here also about CCRC views? (like in your next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691499/i-cant-seem-to-get-cleartools-find-to-work-on-a-simple-query)

Comment: Yes, we are.  Same project, same system.  Same CCRC view.

Comment: @Jay: in that case, I would recommend the IBM plugin, made to support both CCRC and Base ClearCase views. I have edited the answer.