# I can't seem to get cleartool's find to work on a simple query

Tags: clearcase

Disclamer: I'm very new to Clear Case.

I want to find out what files I've modified on a given date.  I am using a Snapshot view:

```
ClearCase version 7.1.2.0 (Tue Sep 21 12:01:15 EDT 2010) (7.1.2.D100920)
@(#) MVFS version 7.1.2.0 (Tue Aug 10 00:37:25 2010)
cleartool                         7.1.2.0 (Wed Sep 8 12:56:06 2010)
db_server                         7.1.2.0 (Sat Sep 4 01:27:12 2010)
VOB database schema version: 54
```

EDIT: FYI, my view was created via CCRC (Clear Case Remote Client).

Here's what I've tried (from my Windows machine):

```
cd c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name
cleartool
cleartool> find . -element "{created_since(12-Mar-2012)}" -print
cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: ".".
cleartool: Warning: Skipping ".".
cleartool>

cleartool> find . -cview -version 'created_since(12-Mar-2012)' -print
cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: ".".
cleartool: Warning: Skipping ".".
```

The IBM docs are sort of useless, the queries they provide don't work either.  Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must go one directory within your snapshot view in order to be in a Vob.

- `c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name` is the root directory of your snapshot view
- `c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name\aVob` is within a Vob as referenced by the config spec of your snapshot view

Only Vobs contains elements (versions of directories and files), which means your `cleartool find` command can only find said elements within a Vob.

See "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" for more.
See also [`cleartool find` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm).

If you stay at the root level of your snapshot view, you can type:

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

---

However, if you are on CCRC (that is ClearCase Remote Client), you **won't have access to the `cleartool find` command**.
Only a subset of `cleartool` commands are supported: see "[Rational ClearCase Remote Client Command Line Interface (CCRC CLI)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929)".

Comment: To know what vobtag you can use, type `cleartool catcs` to see the config spec and load rules of your snapshot view.

Comment: I cd'd into a few subdirs, now I'm in c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name\VOB_name\folder\src.  When I run "cleartool catcs" I get:  Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.

Comment: @Jay: ok, and if you run the `cleartool catcs` from `c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name\`?

Comment: @Jay: anyway, making the find from `c:\SnapshotViews\my_view_name\VOB_name\` should work, unless the snapshot view is somehow broken.

Comment: I got the same error.  In fact, I tried all the way up the directory chain until I hit the SnapshotViews folder and got the error each time.  From what I can tell, the view itself is fine, CCRC is letting me check in with it...

Comment: @Jay: CCRC! ClearCase RemoteClient. Wait a minute, this is different than Base ClearCase. Let me check.

Comment: omg - I didn't realize that was relevant..  so sorry!  No WONDER!

Comment: @Jay: I have edited my answer to mention the CCRC aspect of your question