# ClearCase - How to Find All Checkins By One User for an Entire PVOB?

Tags: find, clearcase, checkin, cleartool

I have been asked to find every checkin by one specific user across an entire ClearCase Project VOB since a particular date. How might I obtain this information?
I assume it's some usage of the `cleartool find` command, but I've not yet figured out the syntax to get the information that I'm looking for.

I guess I'm looking for a "change set" across every activity of that user across every stream of a given PVOB since a particular date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [`cleartool find`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) (which work for versions created with or without UCM), it should be something like:

```
cleartool find . -user <auser> -version "{created_since(date1)}" -print
```

This is done within a vob, not a pvob, as it search for version (data), not UCM activities (metadata recorded on PVob level)

You need first to go to a view, preferably a dynamic view:

```
cd m:\aView\aVob
# unix
cd /view/aview/vobs/avob
```

As noted by the OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217950/6309), what works is:

- using [create_by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217950/6309) instead of `-user`,
- adding `-all -nvis`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, @VonC! Unfortunately when I start a cleartool find command with a dot following the find command, I get this error: cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: ".".

Comment: @DynothermConnector Sure: you need first to go into a view.

Comment: From this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691499/i-cant-seem-to-get-cleartools-find-to-work-on-a-simple-query it looks like I needed to navigate down one level from the root of my snapshot view. The command is executing successfully now. Thanks!

Comment: The query returns results when I run it on my ClearCase user ID in a snapshot view of a stream that I own; however, it returns no results for the user that I'm looking for. I know the user has made checkins within this VOB -- but the user has not made checkins in this particular stream. Would I need to create a snapshot view of a stream that the other user had created in order to find that user's checkins?

Comment: @DynothermConnector try with `-all`: `cleartool find . -all`. Also try with `-nvis`: `cleartool find . -nvis...`

Comment: This tip was very helpful. I just posted as an Answer the syntax that I ended up using. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

With the repeated help of (and huge thanks to) @VonC, here is what I wound up using, at a command prompt (not in a ClearTool session), with my working directory set to the directory just beneath the root of my snapshot view:

`cleartool find . -all -name "*" -version "{created_by(<userid>) && created_since(dd-Mmm-yyyy)}" -print > <absolute path to output file>`

**Update:** The command below, which was originally my answer, returns *only* invisible files:

`cleartool find . -all -nvisible -name "*" -version "{created_by(<userid>) && created_since(dd-Mmm-yyyy)}" -print > <absolute path to output file>`

Comment: Grat! +1. I have referenced those elements in my answer for more visibility.